# Sound wave equation in 3D closed Box

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

We have the sound wave equation

$\Delta p - \frac{1}{v^2} \frac{d^2}{dt^2} p = 0$

in a closed Box. So we got Dirichlet boundary conditions and I can combine the solution for the 1D case to a 3D solution. In my quantum physics course we multiplied the 1D solution but in this lecture the professor actually added the solution.

$ p(x, y, z, t) =  (\cos(\frac{n\pi}{L}x)+ \cos(\frac{k\pi}{L}y) +\cos(\frac{l\pi}{L}z)) \cdot \exp(i\omega t)$

My exam is tomorrow and I am confused why this is the solution.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your box? I suppose it is $[0,L]^3$. You are saying that $p(\text{boundary}, t) = 0$, but the solution you propose does not satisfy this boundary conditions. For example, if $x=0$ the solution is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Either you are dismembering what was taught or your professor. I don't want to speculate who made the mistake, but the solution by your quantum physics professor is correct. The separation of variables method assumes that the solution is of the form:
$$ p(x,y,z,t) = X(x).Y(y).Z(z)e^{i\omega t}$$

So all your cosines need to be multiplied. I hope this helps. Good luck!